# Inject service in templateUrl in angular component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a web app with directives in which the template url is build through a factory, but sometimes I also need the value of one of the attributes, so I do something like this:

```
myDirective.$inject = ['myFactory'];

function myDirective(myFactory) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        bindToController: {
            ...
        },
        controller: myDirectiveController,
        templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
            return angular.isDefined(attrs.myval) ? myFactory.url() : myFactory.altUrl();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm changing a few of these to components, and I didn´t manage to do the same, as now components are objects instead of functions.

I can do without using attrs, like this

```
angular.component('myDirective', {
bindings: {
    ...
    },
    controller: 'myDirectiveController as vm',
    templateUrl: function(myFactory) {
            return myFactory.url();
    }
}
```

but if I try to use also the attrs

```
angular.component('myDirective', {
bindings: {
    ...
    },
    controller: 'myDirectiveController as vm',
    templateUrl: function(elem, attrs, myFactory) {
            return angular.isDefined(attrs.myval) ? myFactory.url() : myFactory.altUrl();
    }
}
```

I get an angular error. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because with a [`component`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider#component), `templateUrl` became an injectable function:

> If `templateUrl` is a function, then it is injected with the following locals:
>   
>   `$element` - Current element
>   
>   `$attrs`- Current attributes object for the element

This means you can inject `$element` and `$attrs` like any other service, factory, value, etc. you would inject into the `templateUrl`. This is instead of just receiving the `element` and `attrs` as always the first 2 parameters (that can be named anything), like the `templateUrl` in a `directive`:

Directive:

```
templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs)
```

Component:

```
templateUrl: function(someService, $attrs, $element, someOtherService)
```

By this logic, in the example you showed above, the error is coming from the fact that angular can't find a service or local with the name `elem` or `attrs`.